# RDLC report is giving ObjectDataSource1 could not be found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I am implementing `RDLC` report in my aspx page but I am getting error as

> RDLC report is giving 'ObjectDataSource1' could not be found error

I implemented the functionality from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252073.aspx).

The result came was

[image: RDLC image]

here is my code:-

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="500px" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
        WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
        <LocalReport ReportPath="BookingReport.rdlc">
            <DataSources>
                <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
            </DataSources>
        </LocalReport>
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="GetData" 
        TypeName="DataSet1TableAdapters.XXACL_PN_CUSTOMER_ENQUIRYTableAdapter">
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Kindly let me know what is wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the pages loaded it is looking for the ObjectDataSource1

I had the same error and I put code on page load.

'This is your dataset or collection you could set it equal to nothing

```
       Dim myOutputData = New MODEL.RptCollection


        OutputReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local

        Dim lr As LocalReport = OutputReportViewer.LocalReport
        lr.DataSources.Clear()

        OutputReportViewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = True
```

'This is the folder where your report is.
            lr.ReportPath = "Reports\rptAll.rdlc"

```
        Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("ObjectDataSource1", myOutputData)

        lr.DataSources.Add(rds)
        lr.Refresh()

        OutputReportViewer.DataBind()
```

Comment: Mine works.  But I had the same error you had.  I added this code to make it work.  I put this code in a method called LoadDummyReport() and I call it on the page load.    Model is just the namespace of where my collections are.  So I am calling the model namespace and then the RptCollection object.  I set everything to nothing so when the report first comes up it is blank.  So in this case its a New Collection so it has no records at all.  I don't fill it with records.

Comment: I have a bunch of reports and I programmatically bind them each individually depending on some controls conditions and date ranges.   myOutputData would be the same as your DataSet1

Answer (score 0):

From your error:
the type specified in the TypeName property....

TypeName from the ObjectDataSource looks like it points to a strongly typed dataset that you have in you project somewhere

try to open the designer of that dataset and update the tableadapter to verify that the file is not corrupt